# PHP how to add a list items inside another list items

Tags: php, json, list

I have a list of financial launch. Each launch may or may not have multiple payments. So for every financial launch I look for a list of payments. I would like this list to be within its corresponding financial launch.

My complete function:

```
    public function customerInvoice()
    {
        $_customer = filtra_int($this->input->post('cliente_id'));
        $this->redireciona_id_nula($_customer, $this->url . '/ficha');
        $_view = [];
        $this->load->helper(['filter', 'string', 'currency', 'validate', 'phone']);

        $_view['glyph'] = 'user';
        $_view['enterprise'] = $this->enterprise;
        $_view['buttons'] = $this->_getFormButtons($_customer, $this->url . '/ficha');

        $this->load->model('lancamento_model', 'lancamentoModel');
        $_view['releases'] = $this->lancamentoModel->getCustomerRelease($_customer);
        foreach ($_view['releases'] as $i => $value) {
//            $_view['releases']['order'][$i] = $this->lancamentoModel->getCustomerOrder($value->id);
             $value['order'] = $this->lancamentoModel->getCustomerOrder($value->id);
        }

        $this->addBreadcrumb('Lançamentos', base_url() . 'lancamentos');
        $this->addBreadcrumb('Ficha', base_url() . 'lancamentos/ficha');
        $this->addBreadcrumb('Exibir');

        $this->extras['css'][] = $this->load->view('lancamentos/consulta/ficha_cliente/form/css', null, true);
        $this->extras['scripts'][] = $this->load->view('lancamentos/consulta/ficha_cliente/form/js', $_view, true);

//        $pagina = $this->getHtmlPagina('Ficha cliente', $_view);
//        $this->load->view('lancamentos/consulta/ficha_cliente/view/view', $pagina);


        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode($_view));
    }
```

json result:

```
 {  
   "release":{  
      "0":{  
         "id":"380",
         "data_vcto":"2016-01-15",
         "data_emissao":"2016-01-15",
         "documento":"292\/1",
         "vlr":"67.00",
         "vlr_divida":"0.00"
      },
      "order":[  
         [  
            {  
               "id":"142206",
               "data_vcto":"2016-01-15 09:59:24",
               "vlr_desconto":"0.00",
               "vlr_multa":"0.00",
               "pago_em":"2018-11-19 09:59:24",
               "conta_nome":"Caixa",
               "tipo_nome":"Vendas",
               "vlr_movimento":"67.00",
               "tipo_pagamento_nome":"Dinheiro"
            },
            {  
               "id":"213",
               "data_vcto":"2016-01-13 09:59:24",
               "vlr_desconto":"0.00",
               "vlr_multa":"0.00",
               "pago_em":"2018-11-19 09:59:24",
               "conta_nome":"Caixa",
               "tipo_nome":"Vendas",
               "vlr_movimento":"22.00",
               "tipo_pagamento_nome":"Dinheiro"
            }
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

I would like something like that

```
{  
   "release":{  
      "0":{  
         "id":"380",
         "data_vcto":"2016-01-15",
         "data_emissao":"2016-01-15",
         "documento":"292\/1",
         "vlr":"67.00",
         "vlr_divida":"0.00",
         "order":[  
            {  
               "id":"142206",
               "data_vcto":"2016-01-15 09:59:24",
               "vlr_desconto":"0.00",
               "vlr_multa":"0.00",
               "pago_em":"2018-11-19 09:59:24",
               "conta_nome":"Caixa",
               "tipo_nome":"Vendas",
               "vlr_movimento":"67.00",
               "tipo_pagamento_nome":"Dinheiro"
            },
            {  
               "id":"213",
               "data_vcto":"2016-01-13 09:59:24",
               "vlr_desconto":"0.00",
               "vlr_multa":"0.00",
               "pago_em":"2018-11-19 09:59:24",
               "conta_nome":"Caixa",
               "tipo_nome":"Vendas",
               "vlr_movimento":"22.00",
               "tipo_pagamento_nome":"Dinheiro"
            }
         ]
      }      
   }
}
```

it is possible ? And what do I have to do in the foreach?

**Update**: I did as @Yulio Aleman Jimenez suggested...but after that the error appeared

**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\beauty\application\controllers\Lancamentos.php on line 829**

**Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

[Error Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MThQw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change your code like this:

```
$_releases = $this->lancamentoModel->getCustomerRelease($_customer);
foreach ($_releases as $i => $value) {
    // try with this changes
    $value = $this->lancamentoModel->getCustomerOrder($value->id);
    $_releases[$i] = (object)array_merge((array)$_releases[$i], array('order' => $value));
}
```

The thing is to store the array of orders in the `order` of each release.

## Update

You have working with objects, it's the reazon you have to cast to `array`, add new values in `order` and then cast to `object`.

Comment: i am getting this error:  Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\beauty\application\controllers\Lancamentos.php:829). Line 829 is your code..

Comment: Can you show the portion of code around the line 829? It seems that error doesn't related to the code of your initial question.

Comment: Check this answers to find a possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php, update your question to get more help or make another new question.

Comment: I update my question... had no mistakes before. I just wish I had my json in the format I said. After doing as you suggested the error started appearing. Any suggestion ?

Comment: I solved my problem: foreach ($_view['releases'] as $i => $value) {
                
                $_view['releases'][$i]->payments = $this->lancamentoModel->getCustomerOrder($value->id);
            }. Thanks for support!